# Flutter GridView.builder not scrollable

Tags: flutter, gridview, scrollview

I have a screen with different components, one of which is a GridView.builder which will not scroll no matter what I do.

I have tried different methods, and nothing is working at all, so I will share what I am trying currently:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body:  Container(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  //Some widgets here, some images, some buttons.   This section scrolls perfectly.
                ],
            SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              GridView.builder(
                  //physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: imageURLlist.length,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 1,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListView(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.network(
                          imageURLlist[index],
                          height: 150,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),   
}
```

The GridView section populates with images, and that's great, but it is not scrollable.   I can scroll down to it, but as soon as I reach this section I lose the ability to scroll completely and I cannot work out why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in `GridView` and `ListView` 
In your case, you can work without `ListView`

```
GridView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
...             
ListView(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> imageURLlist = [
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=10",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=11",
    "https://picsum.photos/250?image=12"
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: Container(
            child: CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [
                Container(color: Colors.red, height: 150.0),
                Container(color: Colors.purple, height: 150.0),
                Container(color: Colors.green, height: 150.0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
            GridView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: imageURLlist.length,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 1,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListView(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.network(
                        imageURLlist[index],
                        height: 150,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
          ]))
        ])));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi mate,  thank you for your response.   I can see in your screen capture there that you have the same issue as I do after getting this working:  a large amount of white space between the images.   You have any idea how to remove this?

Comment: Actually I just found a random comment on another thread with the answer:  childAspectRatio: 2.   I  will update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I have got this working now:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body:  Container(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  //Some widgets here, some images, some buttons.   This section scrolls perfectly.
                ],
            SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              GridView.builder(
                  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: imageURLlist.length,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 1,
                    childAspectRatio: 2,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListView(
                      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.network(
                          imageURLlist[index],
                          height: 150,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),   
}
```

Basically, both the GridView.builder AND the ListView child need to have physics: ScrollPhysics() or it will not work.

Hope this helps someone else who is confused.