# How to set horizontal list separated height dynamic as per content in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]    List drConsultationModelList = [
DrConsultationModel(
"Doctor\nConsultation",
"Video Call with \nIndia’s best Doctors",
icon_dr_consultation,
),
DrConsultationModel(
"Medicines",
"Get Delivery at \nhome",
icon_medicine,
),
DrConsultationModel(
"Lab Tests",
"Book Lab Test at \nyour Home",
icon_lab,
),
DrConsultationModel(
"Homecare",
"Get treated at Home",
icon_homecare,
),
DrConsultationModel(
"Surgeries",
"Access best Doctors \nFrom the best Hospitals",
icon_surgeries,
),
DrConsultationModel(
"Radiology",
"X-ray/CT SCAN /MRI",
icon_radiology,
),
];

So drConsultationModelList is my model type of list.

```
 /*Grid layout*/
                          Container(
                            height: 225.h,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            child: GridView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              primary: false,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 16.w, top: 8.h, right: 16.w),
                              gridDelegate:
                                  const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                                      childAspectRatio: 0.5,
                                      mainAxisSpacing: 16.0,
                                      crossAxisSpacing: 0.0),
                              itemCount: drConsultationModelList.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    // print("cick tayu"+i.toString());
                                    if (i == 0) {
                                      Get.to(
                                          () => const AllSpecialityListView());
                                    } else if (i == 1) {
                                      Get.to(
                                          () => const Search_Medicine_view());
                                    } else if (i == 5) {
                                      Get.to(() =>
                                          const RadioLogicalAvailableTestListView());
                                    }
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: 210.w,
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.h),
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 16.w,
                                        bottom: 10.h,
                                        right: 20.h,
                                        top: 10.h),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.r),
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      boxShadow: const [
                                        BoxShadow(
                                          color: Color(0x14000000),
                                          offset: Offset(
                                            0.0,
                                            4.0,
                                          ),
                                          blurRadius: 14.0,
                                          spreadRadius: 0.0,
                                        ), //BoxShadow
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Column(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                              Text(
                                                drConsultationModelList[i]
                                                    .tvTitle,
                                              //  textScaleFactor: 1.2,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontFamily:
                                                        fontInterSemibold,
                                                    fontSize: 15.sp,
                                                    color: blackes_1a1b25),
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: 4.h,
                                              ),
                                              Flexible(
                                                child: Text(
                                                  drConsultationModelList[i]
                                                      .tvSubTitle,
                                                  textScaleFactor: 1.0,
                                                  maxLines: 2,
                                                  overflow:
                                                      TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontFamily:
                                                          fontInterRegular,
                                                      fontSize: 11.sp,
                                                      color:
                                                          dark_silver_6a7382),
                                                ),
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Stack(
                                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            Container(
                                              height: 50.h,
                                              width: 50.w,
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: const Color(0xffe7f5f0),
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(8.r),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            SvgPicture.asset(
                                              drConsultationModelList[i]
                                                  .imgLogo,
                                              width: 34.w,
                                              height: 34.h,
                                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
```

Now the problem is that, to show layout in listview I have to pass fixed height in sizebox. If I remove height then layout will be gone. So, How do I display item layout without giving fixed height in sizebox.

Fixed height problem issued when we incresed device default font size. So, cant fixed layout height. Plz give solution, Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63111757/10910438 use custom scroll view.

Comment: yes. but in my case it works perfect in vertical listview. I only gets problem with horizontal listview

Comment: Secondly, I already took singlechild scrollview as parent widget in screen

Comment: what you what to achieve can you upload your screenshot of that UI ?

Comment: I have updated my question with UI. Now this list is horizontal listview. and I have given fixed height. But when I increased my device's default size in large In that case, Bottom card text is cutting. Now Plz guide me what can I do In case of fixed list view height.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you can't assume the height of the children. The horizontal ListView takes up all height possible and when you do not provide a defined height, it will give you renderflex error. The ListView can not know the height of all children during build. The builder only calls children that are in view. So it is important for horizontal List view to have a defined height orelse you will have unexpected behaviour while scrolling.
Use MediaQuery or LayoutBuilder to size your listview's height with different screen sizes.

To detect text size changes from settings, you can use the following code:

```
double textScale = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;
```

The default text size is 'Default' in settings. So, if you print textScale you will get value as 1. The largest text size in settings will give you a value of 1.30. You can scale your container height with this value.

Comment: So Is it valid to give fixed hight ?

Comment: We can not figure out how much device text size will increase. In horizontal listview item text are set as per device default size. I also tried by giving MediaQuery but sometimes it takes extra space if user selected medium text size.

Comment: Yes you have to give height to a horizontal list view or create your own list widget that will scroll horizontally. And about font size, you can create a function that will change the height of ListView dynamically. Lets say for small text give height 20, for medium give height 40

Comment: But how do we came to know that device size is medium, small or large. Because that will change by user.

Comment: I have updated my question with UI. If I increased font size the bottom card text is cutting.

Comment: Check if text scale factor solves your problem.

Comment: Let's say you have a container height set to 200. If you do (200 * textScaleFactor) when the text size is default the container will be 200 but if user has set largest text size from settings then the container height will be (200*1.30)

Comment: But in our case, font size is increasing not height of listview. listview size will be as it is.

Comment: Now, the problem is how do we know that text size is increase ?

Comment: I understand your logic. but I dont know how to get font height when user is changing default text size from his/her device !!